# How so I set an inline span to have the same height when containg text in both Chrome and Firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox, google-chrome, cross-browser

I have the following style:

```
  background-color: #C9C5BC;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 3px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor:pointer
```

the HTML element is

```
<span class="name-indicator">NameIndicator1</span>
```

IT looks like this is Firefox (desired)

[image]

and in Chrome it looks like this (wrong)

[image]

The problem is that in chrome there is no white space between the span elements and it is caused by the fact that in FF the height is 13px and in Chrome it's 15px, when setting the font size in chrome to 7px I achieved the right effect.

How can I fix this to be the same on both browsers? I want to keep the font-size to be 10px

**EDIT:**

I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zZJef/) please take a look at both FF and Chrome

Comment: Doesn't look like there is a problem with the span itself. Can you post markup/css of the container too? Create a fiddle maybe?

Comment: Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zZJef/

Comment: Sadly the fiddle didn't clear it up because I was more interested in the CSS of the container element on those `span`. However check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that the `codes` in the stackoverflow answers look similar to your provided image (2nd one). If you put this CSS `line-height: 21px` on the container `.wmd-preview p`, then a separation appears between the codes. So your problem could be solved by adding line-height to the container of those `span`.

Answer (score 1):

To have better chance of achieving same results across many browsers use `css-reset` at the beginning of your page. This little piece of css will make sure that all elements have same default values in all browsers. You can get one from [here](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).